# Sort an array numerically

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort an array of strings numerically in php.
Each string beginns with a number.

The content of the array looks like this:

```
1_some-str
2_some-str
3_some-str
4_some-str
...
10_some-str
11_some-str
```

With sort() the output is like this:

```
10_some-str
11_some-str
1_some-str
2_some-str
...    
9_some-str
```

How can I achive, that the array gets sorted upwards from from 1-11?

**Edit:**

`natsort()` did not work.

`sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)` did the job! Thanks.

Comment: use natsort() Ref:http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: Try `natsort`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your problem:

```
$ar = [
    "1_some-str",
    "2_some-str",
    "4_some-str",
    "3_some-str",
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ar);
echo "</pre>";

natsort($ar);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ar);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Natsort

```
    <?php
$myData=array(
"1_some-str",
"5_some-str",   
"3_some-str",
"4_some-str",
"2_some-str",
);

echo "<pre>";
natsort($myData);
print_r($myData);

?>
```